# Issue with clearing multiline textbox in WinForms application

Tags: winforms, textbox

I have a multiline TextBox in my app whose text I want to clear.

The problem is that when I clear the text using

```
textBox.Text = "" 
or 
textBox.Clear()
```

only the first line is cleared. The other lines are still there but cannot be deleted, and if I start typing into the textbox, the other lines will be overwritten, which leads me to think that it is a re-paint issue, but can't figure out why this happens.

The textbox is in a custom User Control inside a form which can be minimized. The issue appears after the form is minimized then restored.

I tried calling `Refresh` on the control and on the textbox to trigger repainting but it doesn't work.

Is there another way to trigger the repaint event to solve this issue ? Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT:

Here is a sample of the code. The `ShowForm` method is called to restore the minimized form.

```
    public static void ShowForm()
    {
       if (!myForm.Visible)
       {
          myForm.PopulateForm();
          myForm.Show();
          myForm.Activate();
          myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
       }
    }
```

and inside `PopulateForm` (which is a method of `myForm`), I clear the text of the textbox:

```
   public void PopulateForm()
   {
       this.myControl.myTextBox.Clear(); 
   }
```

`this.myControl` is the user control which contains the textbox

Comment: Could you provide your codes?

Comment: The thing which you have given in your question is not happening in my case for a custom User textbox. Its clearing the data successfully with textBox.Clear() command.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo: I have added a snippet from my code into the post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This was caused by the `DoubleBuffered` property being set to false for the user control.

After setting it to True, the textbox is being rendered properly.

Comment: @SzilardD I have tried textbox.Clear() method, it is working fine here. Is any other event or code related to textbox control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, this was due to a repaint issue. It was caused by the `DoubleBuffered` property being set to false for the user control.

After setting it to true, the textbox is being rendered properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Textbox with multiline, I just did a `MyTextBox.Refresh()` after `MyTextBox.Clear()`.